# Multiple Android applications using the same App Namespace in Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to release multiple applications on Android. These are part of the same family with functionality that is closely related.

For this purpose, I would like to share the custom stories that have been created on Facebook - it makes a lot of logical sense. Unfortunately, in creating a second application, I am unable to re-use the namespace that has been created for the first one.

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.